# Expansion of 3-connected graphs gives 3-connected graphs

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness, graph-connectivity

So I am working on this graph theory problem which says: An expansion of a graph $G$ is formed by subdividing two edges of $G$ (subdividing an edge $vw$ means replacing $vw$ with a path $vxw$ through a new vertex $x)$) and adding an edge between these 2 new vertices. Prove that if $G$ is 3-connected, then any expansion of $G$ is also 3-connected. Obtain the Peterson graph from $K_4$ by repeated expansions.

Now I was able to obtain the Peterson graph so that part is okay. For the proof I was thinking I have $G$ which is 3-connected and I obtain $G’$ by expanding $G$ (say I had edges $xy$ and $wz$ and I subdivided them to get $xsy$ and $wtz$ and the edge $st$). To prove $G’$ is 3-connected I want to show that if I remove a vertex from $G’$ I get a 2-connected graph and thus an ear decomposition. If the vertex $v$ I remove is not $s$ or $t$ then the ear decomposition for $G-v$ is supposed to give me that of $G’-v$ somehow and then I don’t know what to do with $G’-v$ when $v$ is $s$ or $t$.

Also, is there a way to do this using Menger’s theorem on internally disjoint paths?

Comment: You can use Mengers criterion. There are a few cases to check, but only those involving at least one of the new vertices. You can reduce this to two cases by symmetry. In all cases, you can build the paths you need using the paths guaranteed by Mengers theorem applied to pairs of the adjacent (original) vertices. Btw this construction appears in here : https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0060102 . I've heard it and some related constructions called Barnette-Grunbaum operations, you can find more under that search term.